# search through node list of elements using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('#divConfirm span');

spans.length = 43.
```

Here is what spans looks like

```
spans: [<span id=​"ctl00_cphBody_lblTitleOrder" style=​"color:​#003300;​font-family:​Verdana;​font-size:​18px;​">​Reservation Confirmation​</span>​, <span id=​"ctl00_cphBody_lblOrderNumber" style=​"color:​#003300;​font-family:​verdana;​font-size:​20px;​">​Reservation Number: 604905​</span>​, <span id=​"ctl00_cphBody_lblDate" style=​"color:​#003300;​font-family:​Verdana;​font-size:​18px;​">​Excursion Date: 8/1/2016​</span>​...
```

This list of spans contain data and they each have an `id` attribute. I would like to regex search this `id` to retrieve a corresponding data point.

I would normally do something like e.g. `spans.querySelectorAll("spans[id*='OrderNumber']")[0].`

But since all the elements are already a `span` it does not seem to work.

How can I search through spans based on regex? I considered converting spans node list into an array but then Google says you cannot use regex with `indexOf`, so using `querySelectorAll()` with the node list and regex `*=` seems the way to go.

So as an example, how would I retrieve the second item in spans, the `OrderNumber` span element?

Comment: Simply omit the `span`: `spans.querySelectorAll("[id*='OrderNumber']")[0]`. Or, better yet, why not use `document.getElementById(OrderNumber)`?

Comment: thanks but Uncaught TypeError: spans.querySelectorAll is not a function(…)

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for the job, just fix your query selector: `document.querySelector('#divConfirm span[id*="OrderNumber"]')`. Of course, this is a silly selector when you should just update your elements to use classes and then you could select with `document.querySelector('.confirm .order-number')`

Comment: @zzzzBov yes that would work. But would it technically be "better" to narrow down the html required just once, then search through this smaller piece?

Comment: @DougFir no. native DOM queries are faster than interpreted JS that then  runs its own shoddy search. It's premature optimization to even think about the performance of a selector like that.

Comment: @zzzzBov OK thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no `querySelectorAll` method in NodeList object. So, you just can't use `querySelectorAll` on the `spans` NodeList.

But you could use hand-written list filters like that:

```
var filtered = Array.prototype.filter.call(spans, function (item) {
    return /OrderNumber/.exec(item.id);
});
```

Or in ES6:

```
let filtered = Array.prototype.filter.call(spans, (item) => /OrderNumber/.exec(item.id));
```

Another way is to store a reference to `#divConfirm` element, and then use `querySelectorAll` on it:

```
var filtered = divConfirm.querySelectorAll('span[id*="OrderNumber"]');
```